# Is it possible to determine whether an ActiveRecord attribute has been set, other than to the default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, default-value

We have an ActiveRecord model whose columns have some default values.  It also has a validation condition such that, if the 'profile' property is set to a different value, then the default values are invalid.

What I'd like is to be able to determine whether the attributes have been set *since they were set to the default* so that I can reset them to new, valid values before validation.

Is this possible?

UPDATE: It's not clear what I mean, so I should give code examples.

The table is defined like this:

```
t.column :profile, :string
t.column :contact_by, :string, :default => "phone", :null => false
```

The validation is like this:

```
validate :validate_contact_by_for_profile1
def validate_contact_by
  if (profile == "profile1") && (contact_by != "email")
    errors.add(:contact_by, " must be 'email' for users in profile1")
  end
end
```

So any time we do this:

```
u = User.new
u.profile => profile1
```

We end up with `u` being invalid.  What I want to end up with is that the user's contact_by defaults to "phone", but if their profile is set to profile1, then it changes to "email", unless it has been set to something in the meantime. (Ideally this includes setting it to "phone")

Comment: How are those default values set? You can definitely check if a value has been changed before saving it, but it depends how you set the default value. Shouldn't it be solved at gui-side? Select a different profile and fields should become empty/reset?

Comment: The default value comes from the table in the DB.  A gui-side solution won't help me in the unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED ANSWER:
ok, don't know if I understood, but I'll try :P

you can writing a method to ovveride the profile= *setter*:

```
def profile=(value)
  self.contact_by = 'email' if value == 'profile1'
  super
end
```

this way works as you expect:

```
> n = YourModel.new
 => #<YourModel id: nil, profile: nil, contact_by: "phone", ...>
> n.profile = 'profile2'
 => "profile2"
> n.contact_by
 => "phone"
> n.profile = 'profile1'
 => "profile1"
> n.contact_by
 => "email"
```

as you can see, this way you get want you want. then you can do whatever validation you need .

hope this time helped ;-)

OLD ANSWER:
generally, you set default values during db migration. so when you try to save some data, the ActiveRecord model has blank data, then when saved on db, it gets default values.

according to this, you can play with validations in the model using something like this:

```
validates_presence_of :some_field, :if => Proc.new {|m| p.profile != <default value>}
```

alternatively, you can write a custom validation code, as private method, that will be called from validate:

```
validate :your_custom_validation_method, :if => Proc.new {|m| p.profile != <default value>}
```

btw I suggest you to look at ActiveRecord validations docs: http://guides.rails.info/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Comment: thanks - looks like I need to explain my question better.  I'll have a go.